# I cant reach Mysdcard files

Tags: android

Hi I am using an emulator and I have created an sdcard .I am able to read and write data from/to sdcard But when i try to list files inside my folder using a Listview .I get exception messages I am sure folder exist because I can see it in the DDMS.

these are folder file names

```
 private String filename = "MySampleFile.txt";
 private String filepath = "MyFileStorage";
```

storage/sdcard/Android/data/PackageName/files/

Besides as i mentioned above nothing wrong while reading and writing.I think somethin wrong with the path

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        File root=
                new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/MyFileStorage");
        listDir(root);
      ArrayAdapter<String>adapter=
              new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,fileList);
   this.setListAdapter(adapter);

    }

    private void listDir(File f) {

        File[]files=f.listFiles();
        for (File file : files) {
            fileList.add(file.getPath());

        }
    }
```

this is the exception

```
05-12 05:14:48.626: E/AndroidRuntime(3349): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-12 05:14:48.626: E/AndroidRuntime(3349): Process: com.example.read, PID: 3349

05-12 05:14:48.626: E/AndroidRuntime(3349): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
ComponentInfo{com.example.read/com.example.read.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-12 05:14:48.626: E/AndroidRuntime(3349):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
05-12 05:14:48.626: E/AndroidRuntime(3349):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
05-12 05:14:48.626: E/AndroidRuntime(3349):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
05-12 05:14:48.626: E/AndroidRuntime(3349):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
05-12 05:14:48.626: E/AndroidRuntime(3349):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-12 05:14:48.626: E/AndroidRuntime(3349):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-12 05:14:48.626: E/AndroidRuntime(3349):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
05-12 05:14:48.626: E/AndroidRuntime(3349):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-12 05:14:48.626: E/AndroidRuntime(3349):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-12 05:14:48.626: E/AndroidRuntime(3349):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
05-12 05:14:48.626: E/AndroidRuntime(3349):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
05-12 05:14:48.626: E/AndroidRuntime(3349):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-12 05:14:48.626: E/AndroidRuntime(3349): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-12 05:14:48.626: E/AndroidRuntime(3349):     at com.example.read.MainActivity.listDir(MainActivity.java:32)
05-12 05:14:48.626: E/AndroidRuntime(3349):     at com.example.read.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
05-12 05:14:48.626: E/AndroidRuntime(3349):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
05-12 05:14:48.626: E/AndroidRuntime(3349):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
05-12 05:14:48.626: E/AndroidRuntime(3349):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
05-12 05:14:48.626: E/AndroidRuntime(3349):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried logging the path of the file passed to your list method?
Try getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();

Comment: Yes Leonard I returns /storage/sdcard/android.So changed the path this way .getAbsolutePath()+"data/com.example.read/files/MyFileStorage/"this way but didnt work

Comment: Your null pointer is at line 32, which line is this? Also check your full combined path has a / between what getAbsolutePath() returns and +"data..." it probably should be + "/data.."